# Is the user email address always returned from requestWithGraphPath:@"me"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is the user email address always returned from the Facebook Graph API when a user has authorized my app and I call requestWithGraphPath:@"me" ?

Or is it possible for a user to hide it in their privacy settings?

Thanks!

Comment: The user may choose to give you a *proxied* email, something like: `fbxx5884521551-8555544@facebook.com`. So you may *send* emails to the user but **not** knowing the actual email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only be returned if you prompt them for `email` extended permissions and they accept it (and haven't later re-voked it).

Comment: Even if they approve the email extended permission, is it possible the email would still not be returned? I.E Could they restrict it from their privacy settings?

Comment: No, if you have email extended permissions, you should always get a valid email address. There is a small chance it may be a proxied email but it is still valid.